# Edit data from API Angular CLI

Tags: angularjs, angular-cli

I'am new to Angular development. I'am trying to make an application where you can find all the Starwars characters. I'am using the https://swapi.co/ API. Displaying the characters is easy for me, now I want to give people the ability to add characters and edit characters, I want to have this changes locally because it is a public API so I cannot change the data from the server. Anyone has any suggestions how I can make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You have (at least) two options :

1. Use local storage browser capabilities, (cookies, Web SQL, Local Storage, Session Storage...)
2. Create an API that connects to the Star Wars API to add user capabilities (not the easiest and fastest in my opinion )

Answer (score 0):

Use [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) via [`ngStorage`](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) module.

Create an Angular component/service which:

1. Initializes local storage with https://swapi.co/ API data then does all operations locally.
2. OR Combines https://swapi.co/ API and local storage data as per your logic